# What's causing Internet Explorer to contsantly refresh the iframe when I'm using FB.Event.subscribe?

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer

On facebook.com/thankidahoeducators, I was using the above method to reload the page on login... until I found out the page was inaccessible to Explorer users. They get thrown into some sort of js loop.

Here's the offending code:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
     window.location = 'http://iamtheiea.com/';
});
```

I've disabled the event listening for now... Any help would rock my world!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing your p3p header.  See here for how to implement: http://www.admon.org/how-to-implement-p3p-http-headers-for-cross-site-cookies/